# Displaying just a piece of a variable?

Tags: powershell

```
$string = "@{Samaccountname=Fname.Lname}
```

What's the easiest way to remove "@{Samaccountname=" and the trailing "}" so only the fname.lname are returned?

I've tried `$string.trim("@{Samaccountname=","}")` and `$string -replace {"@{Samaccountname=",""}`

Even tried `$string.trim("@","{","}")` but I assume there is a better way than quaoting each character individually.

Neither of which worked.. I totally suck at regex so I haven't ventured down that path.

Comment: None of these. Show the command where you set $string and we'll show you how to get the value at that time.

Comment: If your output displays `@{samaccountname=fname.lname}`, then you have converted a custom object  into a string. The proper way would be to extract the data you want from the original object and format the output rather than stringifying a custom object.

Comment: Yeah, +1 to what @DougMaurer said - you might have a `... |Select Samaccountname` statement somewhere that should've been `... |Select -Expand Samaccountname` instead :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen You've seen whats in my closet enough times that you are spot on. I had forgotten all about the -expand.

Comment: @AdminOfThings you are correct in your assumption.

Comment: @DougMaurer The other two are right on the money.. $directreports is created from a Get-Directreport $manager -norecurse  | Select-Object samAccountName that I forgot to put an `-expand` in.

Comment: @skeer exactly what we all thought. ;-)

Comment: @all LOL Yeah sorry I was incorrectly assuming I could pick and choose afterwards.  Whoever wants to submit an answer.. or if I can give all of you the checkmark I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An output of syntax `@{propery = value}` is likely a custom object converted to a string. It would be wise to work with the original object, retrieve the target values, and manipulate the retrieved data as required. So if the intention is only to output a property value, then use `Select-Object -Expand Property` or member access `$object.Property`. Otherwise, objects that are not value types will contain properties and their conversion to string will be based on their `ToString()` override method.

```
$users = Get-AdUser -Filter "SamAccountName -like '*doe'"
$PropAndValue = $users | Select-Object SamAccountName # the objects' SamAccountName property and their values
$ValueOnly = $users | Select-Object -Expand SamAccountName # returns the objects' SamAccountName values only

"objects with property and value"
$PropAndValue
"`r`nstringified prop and value of first object`r`n"
[string]$PropAndValue[0]
"`r`nproperty values only`r`n"
$ValueOnly
"`r`nstringified first property value`r`n"
[string]$ValueOnly[0]
```

**Output:**

```
objects with property and value

SamAccountName
--------------
jane.doe
john.doe

stringified prop and value of first object

@{SamAccountName=jane.doe}

property values only

jane.doe
john.doe

stringified first property value

jane.doe
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:
`$string.Replace("@{Samaccountname=","").Replace("}","")`